# display a div on ervery site but not frontpage?

Tags: functions

i want to display a div on every single page, but not on the frontpage. For that i used the following code in the functions.php

```
 if (! is_front_page()) : 
   '<div class="button-kontakt"> <a href="/kontakt"><p>ANFRAGE</p></a></div>';
 endif;
```

But my code is not working? The div is not shown. Somebody could help me with this?

best regards

Tom

Comment: Where do you want to show the div? It has to go somewhere in the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the PHP to echo the div.

`if (! is_front_page()) : 
   echo '<div class="button-kontakt"> <a href="/kontakt"><p>ANFRAGE</p></a></div>';
 endif;`

Unless you just want it on the top of the page, you need to add that code to a template file, not the functions file. If it is something that appears at the bottom of every page except the homepage, putting it in footer.php may be applicable.

Also, have you set the page you don't want to see it on as the front page via the option in the Appearance->Customise menu?

Comment: thanks! The problem was that i had the code in the functions.php. In the footer.php it worked! Why cant i put the code in the functions.php? Thanks man!

Comment: You can put the code in functions.php, but when it runs it won't pay any attention to templates, and will just appear at the top. Putting it in the header.php, footer.php or a tpl_*.php file gives you control over it's positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_page( 'home' ) && ! is_home() ) : 
   echo '<div class="button-kontakt"> <a href="/kontakt"><p>ANFRAGE</p></a></div>';
 endif;
```

or

```
 if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_page( 'home' ) && ! is_home() ) : ?>
   <div class="button-kontakt"> <a href="/kontakt"><p>ANFRAGE</p></a></div>

<?php   endif;
```